# v-model with dynamically added property

Tags: vue.js

I have migrated an app from Vue 1 to Vue 2 and am having an issue with data from an added property on an object.

I am looping through my data:

```
`<template v-for="(treatments, yard) in groupByYard">`
```

and further down:

```
`<tr v-for="treatment in treatments">`
```

groupByYard is a computed value:

```
`groupByYard: function() {
        var result = {};
        var treatments = this.treatments;
        for (var i = 0; i < treatments.length; i++) {
            var treatment = treatments[i];
            var yard = treatment.yard.name;
            this.$set(treatment, 'completed_date', null);
            if (result[yard]) {
                result[yard].push(treatment);
            } else {
                result[yard] = [treatment];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }`
```

I am adding the property **completed_date**
    `this.$set(treatment, 'completed_date', null)`

This sets the property fine but I can't access/change this property using v-model:

```
`<input class="form-control datepicker"
v-model="treatment.completed_date"
data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"
data-date-end-date="0d"
placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"
type="text"  />`
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `this.$set` here, instead you should set the value of `completed_date` as follows

```
this.treatment.completed_date = null
```

This way you will be able to access the property `v-model`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried using:
'treatment.completed_date = null;' but I can still not access this new property using v-model even though it now exists in the data.

Comment: can you post your data function?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I have worked out the issue is actually with the date picker not updating the value, so am working through creating the date picker as a component.